# How to view systemd's runtime global config?

Tags: systemd

systemd has many default values that can be modified by Linux distributions. (By default values, I mean general systemd settings. Not unit specific settings.) How can I see a dump of those values?

For example I am interested to see what `DefaultTasksMax` is.

Comment: If you found one of the answers to be correct, please accept it.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You are looking for `systemctl show -all` for the global property set or `systemctl show $servicename --all` for a particular service.

I found the answer by searching `man systemctl` for first "dump", and then "show", which found the command.

Or to answer your specific question:

```
$ systemctl show --property=DefaultTasksMax
DefaultTasksMax=18446744073709551615
```

`DefaultTasksMax` was added in systemd version 228.

Comment: `systemctl show --property=DefaultTasksMax` outputs nothing for me.

Comment: Try `sudo systemctl show --all | grep DefaultTasksMax`. Also, share what version of systemd you are using.

Comment: No results either. Debian jessie version `215-17+deb8u5`.

Comment: I checked the [Changelog](https://github.com/systemd/systemd/blob/master/NEWS#L1072). This property was added in systemd version 228, which is why you find no default value. The property doesn't exist on your system.

Comment: This answer is more clean.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the `systemd` **system** instance configurations at,

```
/etc/systemd/system.conf
/etc/systemd/system.conf.d/*.conf
/run/systemd/system.conf.d/*.conf
/usr/lib/systemd/system.conf.d/*.conf
```

And the **user** instance configurations at,

```
/etc/systemd/user.conf
/etc/systemd/user.conf.d/*.conf
/run/systemd/user.conf.d/*.conf
/usr/lib/systemd/user.conf.d/*.conf
```

For more information check manpage for `systemd-system.conf`